# matlab - Do I have to clear variables each time I alter my loop index?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

```
for ii=1:5    
a(ii) = (ii)^2;
end
a
```

Say, I alter the end value of loop index from 5 to 4, the answer given is still  [1     4     9    16    25]

Only if I 'clear all' , it gives        [  1     4     9    16 ]

Is this normal?

Comment: I'm sorry is [1 4 9 16] the result of A after you edit the end index or after you run the loop?

Comment: after running the loop with the new value

Comment: I think I understand why. Maybe it's because I didn't preallocate/initialise A

Comment: clear the specific variable is enough also 'clear a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal!

When you run this:

```
for ii=1:5    
   a(ii) = (ii)^2;
end
a
```

As expected by you, it gives you: `a = [1 4 9 16 25]`. Note that the size of `a` is set to be 1x5.

Now when you run this:

```
for ii=1:4    
   a(ii) = (ii)^2;
end
a
```

You actually are replacing the previous values of 1 to 4 index of `a` (with the same values) but you are not doing anything to the 5th index of `a` and thus it remains as it is.

Run the following (without clearing variables) for better understanding:

```
for ii=1:4    
   a(ii) = (ii)^5;
end
a
```

This will give you: `a = [1 32 243 1024 25]`

I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you described is completely normal. As you have first defined an array with 5 elements, the second for loop only changes the first 4 elements of the `a` array.

Notice, however, that there is an alternative to avoid the problem you described.
MATLAB strongly suggests to use [vectorization](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) to avoid such problems.

If you code it as:

```
a=(1:5).^2 % define a
... % some operations
a=(1:4).^2 % redefine a
```

Then not only you do not need to clear the variable, you also get a cleaner, easier to read code. Remember to use element-wise exponentiation `.^`, or else you will get an [error](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-vs-matrix-operations.html).

Also, notice that the `clear all` command is not recommended. You should either `clear`, to remove all variables from workspace, or `clear a`, to clear only the `a` variable, instead of the `clear all`. The [documentation on the clear function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html#btdyzbv-1-ItemType) describes what else you clear with `clear all` and, for most cases, this is not what you want.